# Reset the content index (SharePoint Server 2010)

Tags: search, crawling

according to [that technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621079.aspx) it is possible to reset manually the content index.

I was wondering if that task could be plan to run once a week for instance, automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find no OOB way to do this in stsadm or PowerShell, so you could either write a server specific custom timer job that does this at pre-scheduled interval, or create a PowerShell cmdlet that is called using schedule on the server that runs the Search Service Application.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration;

public static void ResetContent()
{

            try
            {
                SearchContext searchContext = SearchContext.GetContext(ServerContext.Default);
                searchContext.Reset(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to reset content index.", ex);
            }

}
```

[Source](http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--development-programming/programmatically-reset-all-crawled-content-41959.shtml)

Alternatively in PowerShell

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity “SearchAppName”                                                        

if($searchApp -ne $null) {

  $searchAppCtx = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchContext]::GetContext($searchApp)

  $searchAppCtx.Reset($true)

}
```

Corey Roth also coded this functionality as a cmdlet in his [SharePoint PowerShell Community Toolkit](http://sppsck.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reset-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex&referringTitle=Search%20Commands)

Answer (score 0):

didn't try, but you can try in powershell:

```
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$searchapp.Reset($true, $false)
```

then you can schedule the powershell command

Comment: beat me by 43 sec ;-)

Comment: @anders rask: as your answer is more complete than mine, let's say the score is 1:1 (and user472285 be the judge to mark as answer) :)