# 2013 Content Index Reset Timeout

Tags: 2013, powershell, crawling, content

I'm having a problem when I try to reset the content index in SharePoint 2013.
When I try to reset the index from the 'Search Administration Page', the page hangs for about a half-hour then returns "Request Timeout".
I have tried resetting via PowerShell using the `$searchapp.Reset($true, $false)` command from [Reset the content index (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15019/reset-the-content-index-sharepoint-server-2010)
And this also hangs.  I did not see the PowerShell command finish, so I can't say what output it would have.

I just tried restarting the SharePoint server and retried from the 'Search Administration Page' and got a timeout.  I have not retried from PowerShell.  I am assuming I would have the same result as before.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a related issue and following this answer was able to get the search back up and running:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ede11fc6-59a7-47be-893d-dc1ea4c88879/cant-reset-index-sharepoint-2013?Thread:ede11fc6-59a7-47be-893d-dc1ea4c88879=Microsoft.Forums.Data.Models.Discussion&ThreadViewModel:ede11fc6-59a7-47be-893d-dc1ea4c88879=Microsoft.Forums.CachedViewModels.ThreadPageViewModel&forum=sharepointsearch&prof=required

Once restarted the Timer Service (see full instructions) - i reset the index one more time and now search seems to be back to normal.

good luck!

Comment: This seems to have done it, thanks!  I had to wait a little bit for the cache to be rebuilt, but we've got it squared away now.  It also fixed a problem with our backup system that I didn't know about.  Looks like the problem is related either to backup programs or to having less than 24GB of RAM on a single server farm.

Comment: Is this officially documented somewhere in msdn/technet

Comment: Please note that the link no longer works, which is why link answers are generally a bad idea.

Comment: Your answer is a link that opens broken page, deleted content. Next time don't post just link but instead paste whole or crucial parts.