# SP2013 Search Index reset Timeout

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search, sharepoint-on-prem

We have a SharePoint 2013 intranet portal. When I try to reset the search index it times out. Someone have asked the same question here [2013 Content Index Reset Timeout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88444/2013-content-index-reset-timeout)

and it seems this solution works

> http://bit.ly/1UKRzDe 
>   and http://bit.ly/1RjaXcr

Basically the solution is to delete the XML files from this location ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config and then rebuild the search index...

I haven't tried this yet... but is this the officially recommended approach to troubleshoot and fix search index reset issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete config cache XML files. This is standard procedure when OWSTIMER hang out, incremental/full crawl is running endlessly, HDD space is under 2xRAM and so on.

Link from blogs.msdn
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx

Comment: this article was written on 2007... is it still relevant

Comment: This is still relevant. I used this clear config cache in SP2013 when crawl hang out because of little free space on hdd (when hdd free space is below 2xRAM memory, sometimes crawl get stuck because of owstimer error).

Comment: Thanks eVT. it fixed the issue.... but led to another set of issue which I'll post as another question. Btw, do you know how rebuilding the index fix this?